# My MacBook pro 2017 won't boot without power

Tags: startup, ssd, battery, charging

I have a MacBook Pro 2017 (non touchbar model).

The problem is it won't boot without connecting to a charger.
Without a charger it shows a question mark in folder blinking.
When I boot into recovery without charger, my ssd is not shown in disk utility.

However, when I connect to a charger, it boots normally and in recovery it shows my ssd in disk utility too.
When I remove the charger after it boots normally, it works perfectly.

I have reinstalled my Mac OS and I did SMC & NVRAM reset and it won't solve the problem.
Also my battery cycle is only 110.

Do you think it is a ssd problem? or Battery problem? Any guesses?

Comment: Maybe you could start by posting `pmset -g live ; pmset -g custom ; pmset -g ps` in order to get a better idea?

Comment: Should I just put those commands in terminal?